# JQuery: Unable to get value of the property 'bind': object is null or undefined

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have a JQuery error that I am only seing in Internet Explorer 9.

I have tested in Firefox and IE 11 and there is no error, but in IE 9 I get this error...

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'bind': object is null or undefined

I have tracked the error down to this code only:

```
$("#menu").data("mmenu").bind("closed", function () {
});
```

If I remove these lines, then there is no error.

Does anyone know how to get rid of this error in IE 9?

Alternatively, I am happy to disable this section of code for IE 9 only - so if the error cant be fixed, is there a way to disable this code section to remove the error?

Comment: What version of Jquery are you using?

Comment: Currently jQuery v1.7.1

Comment: you can wrap it in a conditional statement. <!--[if IE 9]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 9<br />
<![endif]-->

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: does it work if you split it in two statements? like
`$("#menu").data("mmenu");`
`$("#menu").bind("closed", function () { });`